# 'accidentally' set 'CHANGE MASTER TO' on wrong server

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

while setting up the replication I accidentally did the 'CHANGE MASTER TO' on the master server instead the slave.

When I noticed the mistake I just did a 'STOP SLAVE' on the master and setup the slave then correctly, replication is working.

I am just wondering if there is a need/way to remove this 'change master to' on the master server again, I havent found anything in the Documentation and 'reset master' seems to be something else.

I can't see any issues currently, so maybe I don't need to bother about it. If possible I'd stil; like to know how to correct it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier versions of MySQL, you would run this on the Master

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO master_host = '';
```

and restart mysqld.

For MySQL 5.5/5.6, you would run this on the Master

```
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE ALL;
```

MySQL restart not required

For more details on this, please read [Disconnecting a replication slave is easier with MySQL 5.5+ (RESET SLAVE vs. RESET SLAVE ALL) from PERCONA MYSQL PERFORMANCE BLOG](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/04/17/reset-slave-vs-reset-slave-all-disconnecting-a-replication-slave-is-easier-with-mysql-5-5/)